# what should we write for url in autocomplete ajax code exactly?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, autocomplete

what should we write for url in autocomplete ajax code exactly? should I write the address of that page ? what is GetCategory in this part?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#txtSearch").autocomplete({
              source: function (request, response) {
                  $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url:   '<%=ResolveUrl("~/MasterProfile.master/GetCategory") %>',
                    data: "{'term':'" + $("#txtSearch").val() + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data.d);
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a URL to an endpoint that is going to return data in the format that jQuery Auto Complete expects, as described in [their documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source).

That endpoint can take many different forms. You could use WebMethods or PageMethods, which is what your question most closely resembles. But Microsoft [doesn't support those anymore](https://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2011/12/07/more-reasons-to-not-use-asmx-services-in-new-code/). You can use [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api), but that might be overkill if this is one of the only things you'll be using it for. So what I'll suggest is that you use a generic handler (.ashx).

Add a generic handler to your site, let's call it AutoComplete.ashx and pretend it's at the root of the site. Here's an implementation:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Handler" %>

using System;
using System.Web;

public class Handler : IHttpHandler
{    
    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context)
    {    
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.Response.Write("['testing','more testing','John Doe']");
        context.Response.End();
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
    get {
        return false;
    }
    }
}
```

You should check `context.Request.QueryString["term"]` and filter your returned values accordingly in your handler. And rather than writing a JSON literal, you should probably create a `List<string>` (populated from some data source) and use a JSON serializer to turn it into JSON for you.

On the client side, your URL becomes:

```
url:   '<%=ResolveUrl("~/AutoComplete.ashx") %>',
```